# You have revoked your certificate, so it is no longer valid

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store, app-store-connect

Yesterday I submitted my app to AppStore and I got this mail from Apple i.e:

> Dear My NAME,
>
> You have revoked your certificate, so it is no longer valid.
>
> Certificate: iOS Distribution Team Name: MY TEAM NAME
>
> Any provisioning profiles that include this certificate are no longer
>   valid and must be regenerated for future use.
>
> Best regards,  Apple Developer Program Support

Now, what should I want to do?? will my app to live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no need to do anything. delete the email and go to sleep.

your uploaded build will be fine and if you want to make more apps, download a new certificate.

otherwise, don't download a new certificate and ... go to sleep

Comment: now i have deleted some of the certificates in the developer portal to configure from fresh to fix that issue will that cause any issue to my app which is in review

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned, you have revoked your certificate so you have to download latest one and add that to your project and make provisioning profile with that certificate then submit app again! you should create new certificate!

It can be happen because you might use `automatic code signing and provisioning profile` and at a time of submission you have set certificate that you have. If you are using automatic code signing and provisioning profile then you should keep it as it is at a time of release also!

for right now you can regenerate certificate and provisioning profile and resubmit app with that!

Comment: how can i resubmit my app i cant able to replace to remove my build from itunes

Comment: you should have option something like `remove this version from review`! you can remove current version from there and then you can submit new app with just increase `build number`  no need to change `version number` from xcode!

Comment: yes got it..now i need to delete my keychain also??

Comment: when create a build i forget to change code signing identify  and provisioning profile..i think this cause this issue??

Comment: yeah that could be issue if there were expired one!

Comment: now i have to change my code signing and provisioning profilesbefore build

Comment: there is no need for any of this. all you need to do is delete the email and go to sleep. your app build will be fine and if you want to make more apps, download a new certificate.

Comment: Yeah! Right @robdashnash. It was little misunderstood. For this application you not need to resubmit, for future use you have to use latest certificate! If apple have not reject your app then for this version you not need to resubmit it! @user3549189!